# How to Save all edited-situations and resume all the situations from the last time when opening Emacs again

Tags: emacs, elisp

I learned that to add those codes in .emacs can make Emacs saves automatically  all situations before quitting and start it next time, Emacs can show the last situation and go on editing it.

```
(load "desktop") 

(desktop-load-default)

(desktop-read)

(add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook

         '(lambda()(desktop-save "~/")))
```

but this codes makes a problem that you only can open one Emacs, when you want to start another Emacs at the same time, only the previous one can run.

I want the function saving all situations for the next use, but I also need to start one more Emacs, How can I get the two sides work simultaneously?

Thank you for your help. I am waiting......

Answer (score 0):

Use different desktop files; or use emacsclient instead of emacs to start new editing buffers once you have your main Emacs up and running. There are multiple examples in Google of an `emacs` alias / function / whatever to start Emacs if it is not running, and otherwise run `emacsclient`.